# find the points on the graph according to the value of a tangent line

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $f(x) = \frac{1}{4}x^4 - \frac{1}{3}x^3-x^2$. Find the points on the graph of $f$ where the slope of the tangent line is equal to:

- $-2x$
- $0$
- $10x$.

I don't know if I should start by finding $x$ and $y$ intercepts and go from there?

Comment: tangent line = first derivative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well considering that the slope of a line tangent to $f(x)$ at all Real values of x is $f`(x)$, you would want to derivate your equation, set it equal to each of your values, and solve for the x values of each.

I'll do the last one for you to show you how:

$f`(x)=x^3-x^2-2x=10x$

$x^3-x^2-12x=0=x(x+3)(x-4)$

And finally, $x(x+3)(x-4)=0$ is true when $x=0, -3, 4$